# Applying patch kept in br2-external to a buildroot package

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, diff, embedded-linux, buildroot

I want to apply a patch to buildroot package. I'm using `br2-external` tree to keep my customizations out of buildroot tree. Buildroot can find my patch, but fails when trying to apply it.

I have set `BR2_GLOBAL_PATCH_DIR="${BR2_EXTERNAL_PATH}/board/myboard/patches"` and put the patch in `${BR2_EXTERNAL_PATH}/board/myboard/patches/packagename/0001-name-of-patch.patch`. I generated the patch by going to `buildroot` repo, applying the changes to package, committing them with git and creating a patch from the last commit:
`git format-patch HEAD~1`
So the patch looks like this:

```
diff --git a/package/rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt b/package/rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt
index 155a54693b..630cfa9e00 100644
--- a/package/rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt
+++ b/package/rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-old code line
+new code line
```

However, when I run `make`, during patching the file to patch cannot be found (wrong path)

```
Applying 0001-name-of-patch.patch using patch:
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/package/rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt b/package/rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt
|index 155a54693b..630cfa9e00 100644
|--- a/package/rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt
|+++ b/package/rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt
--------------------------
No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
```

I also tried `rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt` and `cmdline.txt` paths.

What path should I use in the patch file? Should it be relative to package, relative to buildroot repository root, or pointing to package relative to the global patch directory? I followed https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#customize-patches but couldn't find the answer to this question.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot patch the files in the **package/** directory using **make**.  There is no special **.stamp_patched** file written to each **package/<package_name>/** subdirectory to ensure that patches are applied only once and should not be applied again.  Patches are typically applied to the files in **output/build/<package_name>/**.

Comment: Thanks for comment ;) I'm fine with patching it in output/build/<package_name>. All I want is to make the patched package land in my image. The problem here I think is that the source is in buildroot/package/<package_name>, while the patch is in ${BR2_GLOBAL_PATCH_DIR}.

Comment: *"The problem here I think is that the source is in buildroot/package/<package_name>..."* -- Yes, and there is no copy of it in **output/build/<package_name>/**. Perhaps you can patch the *installed* version of the file, **$(BINARIES_DIR)/rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt**, using a post-build script?

Comment: Thanks, that's the alternative I was thinking about, and I went with this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @sawdust its not possible to patch a file in buildroot package directory `buildroot/package/<package_name>`. You can only patch the source of the package, i.e. the source files downloaded to `output/build/<package_name>/`.

I ended up with using a post-build script to modify the file after it has been copied, as described in https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rootfs-custom (option `BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT="${BR2_EXTERNAL_PATH}/board/myboard/scripts/post-build.sh"`)

Comment: You may always fork entire BR repository and apply whatever patches you want. For example, I'm doing like this in https://github.com/andy-shev/buildroot.